# Setting a $2 preset in bash

Tags: bash, input, console

At console input, if I leave $2 blank, I would like it to be 10, how do I do that?
My code is this but its not working

```
${2:-10}
```

I have also tried

```
${2:=10}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
[[ -z "$2" ]] && set -- "$1" "10"
```

Comment: Thanks, the first one checks if its null right? At the second one tho, why do you put $1 instead of $2?

Comment: `[[ ... ]]`checks if string is empty. See `help test`. I used `set` to set positional parameters in current environment: first to value of $1 and second to 10. See: `help set`

Comment: This sets `$2` to 10 even if it set to the null string; check the value of `$#` instead; `[[ $# -lt 2 ]] || set -- "$1" 10`.

Comment: @chepner: Thank you for this hint.